# Name ArrayList from a variable

Tags: groovy

I would like to check if ArrayList with this name already exist and if does not it should create it.

output is another ArrayList which im looping to get the values.

```
for (item in output) {
    if (item.UID.getClass().isArray())
    {
        print ("Yes")
    }
    else
    {
        print ("No")
        def item.UID = []
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example of what you're expecting? Inputs, runnable code, outputs and expected outputs

Comment: I just want to create empty ArrayLists with specific names which I will populate after this.

Comment: It's the "_specific names_" bit I don't understand, and some extra context may help

Comment: UID is the key in the ArrayList named output. I'm looping over it and in the first loop value for item.UID = x, next loop is y. Based on those values i need to create new ArrayLists that are named x , y. So for this example, 2 new ArrayLists should be created.

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (item.UID.getClass().isArray())`

to

`if (item.UID instanceof List)`

---

`Class.isArray()` determines an array but ArrayList is not an array.

Comment: Tnx. Now i only have problem with this error : org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
test.groovy: 51: Unexpected input: '{\r\n    if (test.UID instanceof List)\r\n    {\r\n        print ("Yes")\r\n    }\r\n    else\r\n    {\r\n        print ("No")\r\n        def test.UID =' @ line 51, column 22.
           def test.UID = []
                        ^

Comment: `def` looks incorrect in `def item.UID = []` . it should be just `item.UID = []`. `def` used only for variable declaration.